# AudioKit rolling waveform plot not displaying on physical device

Tags: objective-c, iphone, audio-recording, audiokit

I have been experimenting with AudioKit and have made a sample app to try and plot recording audio and audio from playback. I am seeing an issue though, when I record or playback audio, the rolling waveform doesn't show up in the view on a device. It shows up perfectly fine on sim (11.4) however. I've provided the recording view controller code below for context in how I'm trying to implement this while recording audio.

Any help or being pointed in the general direction would be greatly appreciated.

RecordingVC.m code:

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation FirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [self setupConfig];
    [self setupUI];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void) setupUI
{
    //Configure waveform view
    self.recordingPlotView.gain = 2;
    self.recordingPlotView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: .10 green: .10 blue: .10 alpha: 1];
    self.recordingPlotView.color = [UIColor colorWithRed: .44 green: .44 blue: .44 alpha: 1];
    self.recordingPlotView.plotType = EZPlotTypeRolling;
    self.recordingPlotView.shouldFill = YES;
    self.recordingPlotView.shouldMirror = YES;
    [self.view addSubview: self.recordingPlotView];
}

- (void) setupConfig
{
    self.isRecording = NO;
    [AKSettings setAudioInputEnabled: true];
    [AKSettings setPlaybackWhileMuted: true];
    [AVAudioSession.sharedInstance setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient withOptions: kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker error: nil];

    self.mic = [[EZMicrophone alloc] initWithMicrophoneDelegate: self];
}

#pragma mark - EZMicrophone Delegate methods
- (void)   microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
     hasAudioReceived:(float **)buffer
       withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
 withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels
{
    __weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        [weakSelf.recordingPlotView updateBuffer:buffer[0]
                                   withBufferSize:bufferSize];
    });
}

- (void)   microphone:(EZMicrophone *)microphone
        hasBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList
       withBufferSize:(UInt32)bufferSize
 withNumberOfChannels:(UInt32)numberOfChannels
{
    if (self.isRecording)
    {
        [self.recorder appendDataFromBufferList:bufferList
                                 withBufferSize:bufferSize];
    }
}

#pragma mark - EZRecorder Delegate methods
- (void)recorderDidClose:(EZRecorder *)recorder
{
    self.recorder.delegate = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Utils
- (NSArray *)applicationDocuments
{
  return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
}


- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    return basePath;
}

- (NSURL *)testFilePathURL
{
    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",
                                   [self applicationDocumentsDirectory],
                                   @"test2.m4a"]];
}

#pragma mark - user Interaction

- (IBAction)playButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.isRecording)
    {
        self.isRecording = NO;
        self.playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Record";
        [self.mic stopFetchingAudio];
    }
    else
    {
        self.isRecording = YES;
        self.playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Pause";
        [self.mic startFetchingAudio];
        self.recorder = [EZRecorder recorderWithURL: [self testFilePathURL] clientFormat: [self.mic audioStreamBasicDescription] fileType: EZRecorderFileTypeM4A delegate: self];
    }
}
- (IBAction)stopButtonTapped:(id)sender {
    if (self.isRecording)
    {
        self.isRecording = NO;
        self.playButton.titleLabel.text = @"Record";
        [self.mic stopFetchingAudio];
        [self.recorder closeAudioFile];
    }
    [self.recordingPlotView clear];
    self.recorder = nil;
}

@end
```

RecordingVC.h code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@import AudioKit;
@import AudioKitUI;

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <EZMicrophoneDelegate, EZRecorderDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet EZAudioPlot *recordingPlotView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EZMicrophone* mic;
@property (nonatomic, strong) EZRecorder* recorder;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isRecording;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *playButton;

@end
```

**Small Update:** 
I've managed to get the playback waveform displaying on device by setting the gain in interface builder, even though I was setting it in code during viewDidLoad().

I've tried doing the same (setting the gain for the plot in interface builder) for the recording VC (the code above) but that did solve this as it did for the playback VC.

Comment: Willing to share a buildable project I can try out on my end?  It can be private.

Comment: Yeah absolutely! How do you want to do this? I can provide a share link, from drop box or google drive to you.

Comment: If you're on github already you can send me an invite to the repo so I can push a fix if I comeup with one.  Other than that dropbox is fine.

Comment: Link to zipped project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kfpi0zdd01nyrqw/TestWaveform.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your project and it works on the device the same as the simulator except that the simulator's microphone is the computer's and seems much more sensitive than on the device, so I had to set the gain higher:

```
self.recordingPlotView.gain = 20;
```

before I noticed the waveform.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Regarding the gain, even if the gain is small I should still see the line where the values are 0 for it going across the view right? That has been my experience when using this library. I'm not sure what the issue is. For some reason this project doesn't show the waveform on any of my devices still, but I have recently tried integrating this with another of my projects (similar logic), and it shows up on device and sim there just fine. No worries about this, and appreciate your time. I just wanted to check it wasn't my misunderstanding of something fundamental with this lib.

Comment: Yeah, there are still values going through zero. I don't know why its flaky sometimes. Thanks for accepting the answer.